# Mongoose get _id of referenced model, no matter if it is populated or not

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Given this `Category` Schema

```
{
    title: String,
    parent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true
    }
}
```

Now what if I have an instance of `Category`, but I don't know if `parent` has been populated or not and I need the `_id` (actually just the hex representation) of the `parent`.

Is there a nicer way of doing this: ?

```
var parentID = (category.parent._id || category.parent).toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a nicer way. I did put this in a virtual though.

```
schema.virtual('parentID').get(function() {
    return this.parent._id || this.parent;
})
```

This could easily be made a plugin if it's needed for multiple schemes.